# Download Google Docs document as text file using Google Drive API for Android

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I have been able to set up a Google Drive file picker so that I can read the contents of any file selected by the user. However, I would like to be able to download Google Docs files selected by the user as text files and then read their content, though I have only been able to find solutions to do this using the Drive Rest API, which I believe is separate from the Google Drive API for Android. Is there any solution that would allow me to do this? Currently, my code for downloading files is as follows:

```
final private class RetrieveDriveFileContentsAsyncTask
        extends ApiClientAsyncTask<DriveId, Boolean, String> {

    public RetrieveDriveFileContentsAsyncTask(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackgroundConnected(DriveId... params) throws IOException {
        String contents = null;
        DriveId driveId=params[0];
        DriveFile file = driveId.asDriveFile();
        DriveApi.DriveContentsResult driveContentsResult =
                file.open(getGoogleApiClient(), DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null).await();
        if (!driveContentsResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            return null;
        }
        DriveContents driveContents = driveContentsResult.getDriveContents();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(driveContents.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
            builder.append('\n');
        }
        contents = builder.toString();
        driveContents.discard(getGoogleApiClient());
        return contents;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (result == null) {
            return;
        }
        Intent intent=new Intent(getContext(),NotesActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("setTextTo",result);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: The Android API is a wrapper around the REST API, so you can get some File object? And can you open a document and read the content to a String?

Comment: I can read the content to a string of any file but files created in Google docs. Also, I don't think I can get the same file object.

Comment: Okay, if you can read the content, then you can write that to a text file, so what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @cricket_007 I can't read from Google Docs files- only from text files or other files uploaded to Google Drive by the user.

Comment: Is there an error that occurs when you use a DriveId for a  Google Doc document?

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, when I use a DriveId on the page that allows you to test the export feature of the Drive Rest API, it gives me an error saying that it cannot find the file.

Comment: Does that file need to have share access, perhaps?

Comment: @cricket_007 It shouldn't, as long as you have the access key.

Answer (score 2):

No Google Drive Android API doesn't provide the convert functionality. You would need to use the REST API for that.

Comment: So does the rest API contain a file picker that I can use in place of the one from the Google Drive API for Android?

Comment: No, there's no android file picker provided by the REST API (there's a web file picker). I think in your situation it would be probably best to use the Drive android API to show the file picker. Once the file is selected you can get the resourceId of the selected file (returnedDriveId.getResourceId()) and use that in the REST API requests to perform conversion etc.

Comment: @Shailendra I'm trying to do the same thing. But in order to build Drive Service Instance, you need to have the AccountName which doesn't seem possible to retrieve in Google Drive Android API